# How I can get list item values when I click on list view

Tags: android, listview, contextmenu

In list view my list contains four data  i.e Fine_ID , Street , Area and Car_No. and I want to fetch all this value, when I am clicking on Clamp Vehicle that is my context menu. And I want to pass all this four values into my database but the problem is that when I click on another list its dosent change all that previous value.

here is my clamper activity code

```
public class ClamperActivity extends ListActivity {

 private ProgressDialog pDialog;

 JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

private static final String CAR_NO = "car_no";
private static final String FINE_ID = "fine_id";
private static final String AREA = "area";
private static final String STREET = "street";

JSONArray jsonArray = null;

private static String userId = LoginActivity.user_id; 
private static String fineId1;
private static String street1;
private static String area1;
private static String carNo1;

 ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jsonlist;

 public static String user_id="";

 static String url= "http://192.168.1.7/testkrcs/main/get_clamped";
 static String url1="https://192.168.1.3/testkrcs/main/clamp_vehicle";

 // JSON Node names
 private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_clamper);
jsonlist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();

ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
registerForContextMenu(lv);

new FetchVehiclesTask().execute();
}
@Override   
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenuInfo menuInfo)  
{  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Select The Action");    
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Clamp Vehicle");   
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Cancel");   
}   
@Override    
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
      if(item.getTitle()=="Clamp Vehicle"){  
          carNo1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carNo))
                .getText().toString();
        fineId1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.fineId))
                .getText().toString();
        area1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.area1))
                .getText().toString();
        street1  = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.street1))
                .getText().toString();
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          new ClamperVehicleTask().execute();
      } 

       if(item.getTitle()=="Cancel"){  

      }else{  
         return false;  
      }    
    return true;    
}    

@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
openContextMenu(v);

}


class ClamperVehicleTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String>
{
  protected String doInBackground(String... args )
  {
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("street",ClamperActivity.street1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",ClamperActivity.area1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",ClamperActivity.userId));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine_id",ClamperActivity.fineId1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("car_no",ClamperActivity.carNo1));

 JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1, params);

      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask UID = "+ClamperActivity.userId);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Street = "+ClamperActivity.street1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Area = "+ClamperActivity.area1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Fine ID = "+ClamperActivity.fineId1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Car No. = "+ClamperActivity.carNo1);


      Log.d("ClamperVehicleTask Response", json.toString());
      return null;
  }
}

class FetchVehiclesTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
private ListActivity activity;


 protected void onPreExecute() {
    super.onPreExecute();
    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(ClamperActivity.this);
    pDialog.setMessage("Fetching Vehicles List...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(true);
    pDialog.show();
}

protected Void doInBackground(Void... args0)
{

     System.out.println("Login Street clamper ="+LoginActivity.street);
     System.out.println("Login Area clamper ="+LoginActivity.area);
     System.out.println("Login Uid clamper = "+LoginActivity.user_id);
     JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
        UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();

        String json = userFunction.clamperFetch(LoginActivity.street, LoginActivity.area, LoginActivity.user_id);
        Log.d("Response:",json);
        if(json!=null)
        {
            try{

                jsonArray = new JSONArray(json);
                for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++)
                {
                    JSONObject c = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                     String fineId = c.getString(FINE_ID);
                     String street2 = c.getString(STREET);
                     String area2 = c.getString(AREA);
                     String carNo = c.getString(CAR_NO);

                    System.out.println("FineId = " +fineId);
                    System.out.println("Street = "+street2);
                    System.out.println("Area = "+area2);
                    System.out.println("Car_No = "+carNo);

                    HashMap<String,String>jsonArray = new HashMap<String,String>();
                    jsonArray.put(FINE_ID,fineId);
                    jsonArray.put(STREET, street2);
                    jsonArray.put(AREA, area2);
                    jsonArray.put(CAR_NO, carNo);
                    jsonlist.add(jsonArray);

                }
            }catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else {
            Log.e("JASON Parser", "Couldn't get any data from the url");
        }

        System.out.println("Fetching Response" +json);

           return null;
}
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    // dismiss the dialog once done
    if(pDialog.isShowing())
    {
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }
    System.out.println("Result"+result);

    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
            ClamperActivity.this,jsonlist,
            R.layout.list_item,
            new String[]{FINE_ID,STREET,AREA,CAR_NO},
            new int[]{R.id.carNo,R.id.fineId,R.id.area1,R.id.street1});
    setListAdapter(adapter);
    System.out.println("Adapter"+adapter);

}
}

}
```

like this i am trying to fetch value from list view its not working properly when I am trying to click on another list its remain the same value it didnt change the new value,

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
      if(item.getTitle()=="Clamp Vehicle"){  
          carNo1 = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.carNo))
                .getText().toString();
        fineId1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.fineId))
                .getText().toString();
        area1 = ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.area1))
                .getText().toString();
        street1  = ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.street1))
                .getText().toString();
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          new ClamperVehicleTask().execute();
      } 

       if(item.getTitle()=="Cancel"){  

      }else{  
         return false;  
      }    
    return true;    
}
```

In this way I am trying to pass all four values into database
     class ClamperVehicleTask extends AsyncTask

```
 {
  protected String doInBackground(String... args )
  {
      List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("street",ClamperActivity.street1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",ClamperActivity.area1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",ClamperActivity.userId));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine_id",ClamperActivity.fineId1));
      params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("car_no",ClamperActivity.carNo1));
      JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1, params);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask UID = "+ClamperActivity.userId);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Street = "+ClamperActivity.street1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Area = "+ClamperActivity.area1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Fine ID = "+ClamperActivity.fineId1);
      System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Car No. = "+ClamperActivity.carNo1);


      Log.d("ClamperVehicleTask Response", json.toString());
      return null;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within the `onContextItemSelected` handler you may use `AdapterContextMenuInfo` to get information about the selected item position and even the view associated with the list item. Check
[How to get View in OnContextItemSelected event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17689315/how-to-get-view-in-oncontextitemselected-event).
Calling the `findViewById` method on the retrieved item view, you are able to access text views of the clicked item.
Try also exploiting AsyncTask parameters to pass your strings to the doInBackground() method, instead of static class fields.

```
@Override    
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){    
   AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();
   View view = info.targetView;

   String carNo1, fineId1, area1, street1, uId = userId;
   if(item.getTitle()=="Clamp Vehicle"){  
      carNo1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.carNo))
            .getText().toString();
      fineId1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.fineId))
            .getText().toString();
      area1 = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.area1))
            .getText().toString();
      street1  = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.street1))
            .getText().toString();
      new ClamperVehicleTask().execute(carNo1, fineId1, uId, area1, street1);
  } 

   if(item.getTitle()=="Cancel"){  

  }else{  
     return false;  
  }    
  return true;    
}
```

Changes in doInBackground():

```
protected String doInBackground(String... args )
{
  List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("street",args[4]));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("area",args[3]));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("user_id",args[2]));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("fine_id",args[1]));
  params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("car_no",args[0]));

  JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(url1, params);

  System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask UID = "+args[2]);
  System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Street = "+args[4]);
  System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Area = "+args[3]);
  System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Fine ID = "+args[1]);
  System.out.println("ClamperVehicleTask Car No. = "+args[0]);


  Log.d("ClamperVehicleTask Response", json.toString());
  return null;
}
```

In addition, I would also suggest you to open the context menu in a more correct way (check https://stackoverflow.com/a/8872337/3423110)

```
@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id)
{
    l.showContextMenuForChild(v);
}
```

Comment: hey please write whole code in onContextItemSelected please

Comment: thanks i will check it and will let you know that it will work or not can i catch u after an hour...

Answer (score 0):

You must have stored the List before attaching to the listview using adapter class. The just fetch it by using the `get(position)`.

for eg:- I Have used simple **example for just explaining the concept**.

I hope you know how to add data in the **arraylist**.

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list.xml, list)
listview.setAdapter(adapter)
```

now you have attached that list to adapter class.Then just include the following code on `onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) event`

```
list.get(position)
```

Here are some good [links 1](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html), [this](https://prativas.wordpress.com/category/android/custom-listview-in-android-using-custom-arrayadapter/) and [this](http://www.semurjengkol.com/using-custom-array-adapter-on-android-list-view/) and [this](http://www.learn-android-easily.com/2013/06/listview-with-custom-adapter.html)
Hope it helps

Comment: can you please write the whole code for adapter please I am new in android I dont know much about it.

Comment: I used adapter class in  clas FetchValueVehicle my data is coming from online server now how i can add my data into  onCreate method while using ArrayAdapter

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal check this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15921446/listview-listadapter-with-2-strings-in-android-project

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal this is the best tutorial I advice you to follow for json is http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: @HarshitAgarwal please follow the latest link I gave You its the best and it should workout with ur problem

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have a problem with this you are finding your view globally in main layout while it is a part of you listview so find like this so you can get the values.       public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item){
      if(item.getTitle()=="Clamp Vehicle"){
          carNo1 = ((TextView)listview.findViewById(R.id.carNo))
                .getText().toString();
        fineId1 = ((TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.fineId))
                .getText().toString();
        area1 = ((TextView) listview.findViewById(R.id.area1))
                .getText().toString();
        street1  = ((TextView)listview.findViewById(R.id.street1))
                .getText().toString();
          //Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"calling code",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          new ClamperVehicleTask().execute();
      }

```
   if(item.getTitle()=="Cancel"){  

  }else{  
     return false;  
  }    
return true;
```

}

Comment: carNo1 = ((TextView)listview.findViewById(R.id.carNo)) .getText().toString();  when I am trying this then it shows me an error that listview cantbe resolve

Comment: I defined ListView globally now

Comment: are you click through the ListView.setonitemClicklistener or you are using some different message

Comment: you want to use this method         List_View.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

   @Override
   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
     long arg3) { and find you widgets here through the arg0.findViewByid(what you id is)}}

Comment: you can put this after you set the adapter of listview view you can simply call this in your on create or as well as you can implements the Onitemclicklistener in your activity as well